# I have a problem in displaying images from database to page

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a website with an upload feature for gallery.
The upload works flawless,but it doesn't shows the images on the webpage.
I can not find the error in the code

I have tried to display the image as a background-image for the box I created and with an image tag with the attribute src.
The last method shows me that the website is reading the image but it can not be displayed.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Art Gallery</h2>
      <div class="Gallery-container">
        <?php
        include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery1 ORDER BY orderGallery DESC";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
          echo "SQL statement failed!";
        } else{
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<a href="#">
              <div><img src=url(gallery/img/'.$row["imgfullnameGallery"].');></div>
              <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
              <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
            </a>';
          }
        }


        ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
          echo '<div class="gallery-upload">
            <form action="includes/galleryupload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name...">
              <input type="text" name="filetitle" placeholder="Title...">
              <input type="text" name="filedesc" placeholder="Description...">
              <input type="file" name="file">
              <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
            </form>
          </div>';
        }

      ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong syntax img tag
please update below code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo '<a href="#">
        <div><img src="gallery/img/'.$row["imgfullnameGallery"].'"></div>
        <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
        <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
     </a>';
}
```